# Deserialze is not getting called. IsAuthenticate always return False

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I would like to know why deserializeUser method of passport not getting called when I use session object like this.

```
 app.use(session({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: true }
    }))
```

When I set session as like this

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
}));
```

DeserializeUser is executed with no error. And getting called for every request.